# Run function once both input fields have a value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have 2 input fields, a start and an end.

I have a function that runs on keyup in my second input field - this runs regardless if the first field is empty or not. I also have to buttons that populate either or my input fields.

What I'm asking is, is there a way to add a listener of some sort so that once both fields contain a value my function will run?

Heres a fiddle to hopefully explain better...

http://jsfiddle.net/Zn6UR/1/

**Code**

```
var timer;

function CalculateRoutes(){
    alert('Done!');
}

$( '.end' ).keyup(keyup);

function keyup() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(CalculateRoutes,500);
}

$('.first').click(function(e){
    $('.start').val('Location1');
    e,preventDefault();
});

$('.second').click(function(e){
    $('.end').val('Location1');
    e,preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Surely you can figure this out?!  You're 99% there!

Comment: Just check if the first field has a value on the keyup function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Zn6UR/3/

```
function CalculateRoutes() {
    alert('Done!');
}

function bothHaveValues() {
    if ($('.start').val() != '' && $('.end').val() != '') {
        CalculateRoutes();
    }
}

$('.start, .end').keyup(keyup);

function keyup() {
    bothHaveValues()
}

$('.first').click(function (e) {
    $('.start').val('Location1');
    e.preventDefault();
    bothHaveValues()
});

$('.second').click(function (e) {
    $('.end').val('Location1');
    e.preventDefault();
    bothHaveValues()
});
```